# What does `bash -` do?

Tags: bash, shell

I recently saw the following line:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash -
```

What is the difference between `bash` and `bash -`? I tried running both variants, and they seem to do the same thing.

`man bash` didn't supply an answer either.

Comment: @jhnc Thank you for the correction, I will delete my misleading comments. And thank you for addressing GenoChen's and my misunderstanding explicitly in your answer.

Comment: @triplee that is a very poor choice of duplicate, since none of the answers there discuss the use of the dash to end a list of command line parameters (which I had never seen before - is it unique to bash?). Voting to reopen.

Comment: @joanis My bad, you're right. For the record, the duplicate was about the general convention to let `-` as a file name argument mean, read standard input.

Comment: @joanis see my answer edit. Apparently POSIX include single dash use in shell invocation as an equivalent to `--`, for compatibility with the way that single dash had been used historically.

Comment: @jhnc nice digging, and I guess it makes sense in that old context. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands are identical.

The author probably believes that passing `-` as an argument will make bash read commands from stdin but bash will do that anyway.

In fact, the bash man-page explains that `-` is equivalent to `--` and terminates option processing:

```
--    A  --  signals the end of options and disables further option
      processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as  file‐
      names and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.
```

---

Note that if there was something after the `-`, then behaviour might be different. For example:

```
$ echo "echo foo" > ./-c
$ chmod +x ./-c
$ export PATH=.:"$PATH"
$ bash   -c "echo bar"
bar
$ bash - -c "echo bar"
foo
$
```

---

Note also, it is **not** the case that using `bash -` makes it a login shell. This can be demonstrated by adding something printable to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
$ export HOME=$(mktemp -d)
$ cd
$ echo "echo login shell" > .bash_profile
$ echo "echo hello" | bash
hello
$ echo "echo hello" | bash -
hello
$ echo "echo hello" | bash -l
login shell
hello
$
```

The meaning in the manpage of "A  login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -" is that the **command name** starts with a hyphen:

```
$ cat .bash_profile
echo login shell
$ ln -s /bin/bash ./notLoginShell
$ ln -s /bin/bash ./-isLoginShell
$ export PATH=~:"$PATH"
$ echo "echo hello" | notLoginShell
hello
$ echo "echo hello" | -isLoginShell
login shell
hello
$
```

---

**Addendum**

Using `bash -` may be a cargo-culted carry-over from a technique used historically to prevent a particular type of security exploit.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) comments:

> On systems that support set-user-ID scripts, a historical trapdoor has been to link a script to the name `-i`. When it is called by a sequence such as:
>
> ```
> sh -
> ```
>
> or by:
>
> ```
> #! usr/bin/sh -
> ```
>
> the historical systems have assumed that no option letters follow. Thus, this volume of POSIX.1-2017 allows the single <hyphen-minus> to mark the end of the options, in addition to the use of the regular "`--`" argument, because it was considered that the older practice was so pervasive.

[unix-faq](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html) explains:

> suppose the script is called `/etc/setuid_script`, starting with:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> ```
>
> Now let us see what happens if we issue the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ cd /tmp
> $ ln /etc/setuid_script -i
> $ PATH=.
> $ -i
> ```
>
> We know the last command will be rearranged to:
>
> ```
> /bin/sh -i
> ```
>
> But this command will give us an interactive shell, setuid to the owner of the script!
>
> Fortunately this security hole can easily be closed by making the first line:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh -
> ```
>
> The `-` signals the end of the option list: the next argument `-i` will be taken as the name of the file to read commands from, just like it should!